# why my training model got only one result?

Tags: python, tensorflow, dataset, google-colaboratory, training-data

I have a problem where the result of my training model comes out with only one output, which is [1]. actually has 2 outputs which are [1] real and [0] fake. I follow step by step from github but when I predict a fake video result it comes out [1]? that means the video is real. Is this coding wrong?

Coding:

```
import tensorflow as tf
import dlib
import cv2
import os
import numpy as np
from PIL import Image, ImageChops, ImageEnhance
from tensorflow.keras.models import load_model
from tensorflow.keras.preprocessing.image import img_to_array, load_img
import statistics
from statistics import mode
```

load model:

```
model = load_model('/content/drive/MyDrive/deepfake-detection-model.h5')
```

coding by using fake videos

```
input_shape = (128, 128, 3)
pr_data = []
detector = dlib.get_frontal_face_detector()
cap = cv2.VideoCapture('/content/drive/MyDrive/deepfake-detection-master/test_videos/eywdmustbb.mp4')
frameRate = cap.get(5)
res=[]
while cap.isOpened():
    frameId = cap.get(1)
    ret, frame = cap.read()
    if ret != True:
        break
    if frameId % ((int(frameRate)+1)*1) == 0:
        face_rects, scores, idx = detector.run(frame, 0)
        for i, d in enumerate(face_rects):
            x1 = d.left()
            y1 = d.top()
            x2 = d.right()
            y2 = d.bottom()
            crop_img = frame[y1:y2, x1:x2]
            data = img_to_array(cv2.resize(crop_img, (128, 128))).flatten() / 255.0
            data = data.reshape(-1, 128, 128, 3)
            #print(model.predict(data)[0][0])
            res.append(round(model.predict(data)[0][0]))
            #res.append((model.predict(data) > 0.5).astype("int32"))

print(mode(res))
```

Output:

```
1
```

The expecting result should be [0] with is Fake videos.